# SPRING MVC database error jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

Thanks for your time

I am getting an error as my project is having 2 modules add driver and add truck for which i am executing the sql query for both but when i execute the query for addDriver module the database exception is throwing stating

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO truck(TRegnNo,VendorName,PurchaseDate,Price,RepairDate,InvoiceNo,RepairCost) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; Column 'TRegnNo' cannot be null; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'TRegnNo' cannot be null
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
```

driver insert sql statement                                                public void insertData(Driver driver) 
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO driver" + "(DLNo,DName,Age,Experience) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

```
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {driver.getLicenseNumber(),driver.getDriverName(),driver.getAge(),driver.getExperience()});
}                                                          Truck Insert code                                                                 public void insertData(Truck truck) 
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO truck" + "(TRegnNo,VendorName,PurchaseDate,Price,RepairDate,InvoiceNo,RepairCost) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql , new Object[] {truck.getTregNo(),truck.getVendorName(),truck.getPurchaseDate(),truck.getPrice(),truck.getRepairDate(),truck.getInvoiceNo(),truck.getRepairCost()});


}
```

Comment: You stacktrace contains `Column 'TRegnNo' cannot be null`. You are trying to set a null value to a DB column that has a non null constraint

Comment: The error "*Column 'TRegnNo' cannot be null*" is pretty clear to me.

Comment: Exception clearly say `Column 'TRegnNo' cannot be null`

Comment: But i am not making an entry in truck table. I am adding a new driver then why it is giving me an error of 'TRegNo' as their is no column in it of that name.

Comment: The stacktrace should be longer than that and at a moment, you should find a line from your sources. Look what happens at that line and show full file or at least some lines around.

Comment: driver insert sql statement

Comment: I have put the code for truck add as well as driver add. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Column `TRegnNo` can not be null. You have to assign a (unique) value to this row.

Comment: But i am not making an entry in truck table. I am adding a new driver then why it is giving me an error of 'TRegNo' as their is no column in driver table of that name.

Comment: It seems that when you add a driver, it triggers this other sql for the truck table. Look in your database manager if there is such a trigger.

Comment: Hi paul i have shared my code for add driver and add truck modules.Please provide your vaulable feedback.

Comment: Somewhere this method is called: `public void insertData(Truck truck)`. My suggestion is that you debug your code and look into the `truck` object. The truck.getTRegNo returns null and therefore the error.

Comment: I have debugged it and traced the issue that was my mistake.    Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out with this :

StackTrace contains `Column 'TRegnNo' cannot be null` pointing to constraints in Truck table, like primary key or foreign key etc..